# I need to get sound level of a specific window

Tags: c#, audio

I'm pretty new to c#, I want to make a program that alerts me if I prefixed window sound volume become too high, for example, I have Spotify running in the background suddenly a high pitch sound then i get an alert, is this possible to do for in a low-level way that I can understand?

I already tried, an open source code that uses cscore, I did make some advancement but its way to advance for me to even keep going with that, this is where the source code I use:

[Getting individual windows application current volume output level as visualized in audio Mixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200825/getting-individual-windows-application-current-volume-output-level-as-visualized/21202235)

I made it, so it sends a message box with the window name that went to high on sound, but it only worked 1 time after the first time I didn't get any more message boxes, if I could just make it so it keeps sending message boxes would be perfect for me

**Edit**
I downloaded the source code of the program linked here, it's at the bottom of the link

I changed

```
var value = audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue();
```

to something like 0.9

and added a messagebox around here:

```
 using (var audioMeterInformation = session.QueryInterface<AudioMeterInformation>()) {
                                        var value = audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue();
                                        if (value != 0) {
                                            if (process != null) {
                                                seenPids.Add(sessionid);
                                                List<double> samples;
                                                if (!sessionIdToAudioSamples.TryGetValue(sessionid, out samples)) {
                                                    samples = new List<double>();
                                                    sessionIdToAudioSamples[sessionid] = samples;
                                                    if(process.MainWindowTitle == "NAME OF MY WINDOW")
                                                    {
                                                        MessageBox.Show("true");
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                var val = audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue();
                                                samples.Add(val);
                                                truncateSamples(samples);
```

I'm getting the message box, but just 1 time, if the high volume sound happens again it won't show the message box again, it just happens once per window.

Comment: and your code is... ?

Comment: For that I guess you need some event, which will be fired when sound level is changed for a certain process. Then you can do your checking inside that event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading the value of the volume in the windows mixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447283/reading-the-value-of-the-volume-in-the-windows-mixer)

Comment: i would think OP is not interested in the mixer setting but the actual peek value that was present in the audio stream in the last few seconds

Comment: yeah im just interested in a way to get a message box each time a sound volumen get to certain level on an especific windows.

Comment: any help would be apreciated